# Replace "box" in image with text

Tags: image-processing

I have an image like:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUImj.jpg)

Where the yellow box (**CODICEFISCALE**) is a field that must to be replaced by stored text in the database and the green box (**firma**) must to be replaced with another image of the user's signature.

How can I do that?
I am open to use any possible solution.

**Update:**
My question is only about replace the boxes (always the same) in the images (the images can be different).

Comment: Your question is very vague. Are you trying to locate the yellow and green boxes, or do you have their coordinates? Are they likely to move between subsequent invications of your program? Are you looking for a Python or Visual Basic answer? Have you worked out the SQL to get the signature? Is your question about fonts or formatting the text? Or placing the text in the inage? Or clearing the yellow/green first? What have you tried?

Comment: @MarkSetchell  no I don't have coordinates. The user can drag and drop the fields where he wants and then upload the image (images are pdf converted so they change but the size of the boxes are always the same).